# Cordova Plugin File Transfer using HTTPS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, ngcordova

Here's my function which I used to transfer image to server. It was working with http url now it gives exception on https url. I think because cordova file transfer plugin supports only http and not https. Can any one help me get this working on https because other things depend on it.

```
  public uploadImg(img, userId) {
/*if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null || credentials.name === null) {
  return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
} else {*/
// At this point store the credentials to your backend!
console.log(userId);
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
  fileKey: 'img',
  fileName: 'name.png',
  params: {action: 'upload_image', api_key: API_KEY, user_id: userId},
  httpMethod: 'post',
  mimeType: 'image/png'
}
console.log('upload function');
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.fileTransfer.upload(img, encodeURI('https://exampledomain.com/api/api.php'), options)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('uploaded image');
      console.log('APi response is' + data.response);

      let img = JSON.parse(data.response);
      console.log(img.status + ' ' + img.message);
      resolve(img)
      // success
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('image failed');
      reject(false)
      // error
    });
});
// } }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/uploading-file-over-https/18614/3) topic helped me and I found the solution finally. I am answering this question so it could help someone. You need to add this chunkedMode=false param in options then it will work with https too. cheers!

Comment: I have set **chunkedMode=false** and it still does't work. I have an app in production, this is a terrible issue. File uploads work fine on my local dev machine, obviously. But they fail over HTTPS with the **BoringSSL SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL** on XCode. The error in XCode Debug Console says **operation failed externally to the library** so I'm not sure if this is a plugin issue, a problem on my production server or what. The SSL Cert. is correct and the mappings are fine. Can anyone please clarify this error.